# Image overlapping text and logo not centering on top of image

Tags: html

My header image is overlapping my text and it is very much annoying me.  Another thing that is buggy is how my logo text leans right of the center of the image.  If someone could help me with both that would be awesome.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2bom0cc/1/

Here are my tags that are probably the most relevant to this:

```css
#index_header {
  position: block;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#index_header img {
  position: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.background_title {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_container">
  <div id="index_header">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="slider" id="index_headerimg" src="http://www.bakeryandsnacks.com/var/plain_site/storage/images/publications/food-beverage-nutrition/bakeryandsnacks.com/regulation-safety/coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-federal-court-australia/9101085-1-eng-GB/Coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-Federal-Court-Australia.jpg"
      />
      <p class="background_title">G.F. Bakery</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your paragraph (text) is inside the `<a>` element. And do you want to display the text under the image in right position? Please explain.

Comment: That should not matter at all. I switched it around and it did not affect anything.

Comment: Do you mean, the text should appear in the right middle, on the image?

Comment: There's no such thing as `position: block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I let myself hold a few assumptions on your code:

First, by the full height and width of the image, I figured that you want the image as a stretched background image. So I replaced the `<img>` with `background-image` (`background` shorthand) in [CSS Backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

From your question I see that you want the title in the center of the bakery background.

I did not get what text is overlapped by the image.
If you want text below the image, please put it in an element **after** `<div id="index_header">...</div>`, as the background is all over that `<div>`.

I had to add `display:inline-block` to `.background_title` class, so that the `vertical-align:middle;` would take effect.

I removed all the absolute positioning to handle better with all the alignments.
Absolute positioning make you manually set all the `top` and `left`, and it's really difficult to do when your code gets bigger.

**Here's you new HTML:**

```
<div class="page_container">
  <div id="index_header">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="background_title">G.F. Bakery</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <p>Some other content...</p> // this text will not be overlapped by
                               // #index_header as long as #index_header
                               // isn't absolutely positioned
</div>
```

**Here's your new CSS:**

```
html, body{   // this is instead of having top:0 and left:0 in #index_header
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.page_container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#index_header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url('http://www.bakeryandsnacks.com/var/plain_site/storage/images/publications/food-beverage-nutrition/bakeryandsnacks.com/regulation-safety/coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-federal-court-australia/9101085-1-eng-GB/Coles-freshly-baked-claims-false-rules-Federal-Court-Australia.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%; // this does the stretching
}
.background_title {
  display:inline-block; // this is to apply the vertical-align of parent
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2bom0cc/6/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much! I tend to over-complicate my code so this really helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text to be under your image and centered, remove the following code:

```
.background_title {
position: absolute;
}
```

Just removing the position will move your text under your image and centered.